# Automating Rails workflow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When working with Rails, is there any way to customize the results from rake commands?

For instance, I use the rake dump task - `rake db:dump` - so that it gets all my locally produced database entries. I would want to expand that to a deployed app so that I can run one command and have a file that can reproduce my DB.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is write a bash script that is just all the commands you need to dump and deploy.

You can also create an alias that runs multiple commands, which might be closer to what you want to do.

Here's a similar question that has answers explaining both:

[How can I define a bash alias as a sequence of multiple commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135644/how-can-i-define-a-bash-alias-as-a-sequence-of-multiple-commands)